# Laravel 4 : Raw Query to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to convert this query to Eloquent:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE who_see='6'
  OR (news.id_user IN
        (SELECT id_user
         FROM koneksi_user
         WHERE to_id_user='$user->id_user'
           AND confirmed='0')
      OR news.id_user IN
        (SELECT to_id_user
         FROM koneksi_user
         WHERE id_user='$user->id_user'
           AND confirmed='0')))
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

So far I have tried this:

```php
$user = \Auth::user();

return \DB::table('news')
        ->where('who_see','6')
        ->orWhereIn('news.id_user', function($query)
            {
                $query->select('id_user')
                ->from('koneksi_user')
                ->whereRaw('to_id_user = $user->id_user');
            })
        ->orWhereIn('news.id_user', function($query2)
            {
                $query2->select('id_user')
                ->from('koneksi_user')
                ->whereRaw('id_user = $user->id_user');
            })
        ->get();
```

But I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: 'sintaks error' pada atau didekat « $ » LINE 1: ... "id_user" from "koneksi_user" where to_id_user = $user->id_... ^ (SQL: select * from "news" where "who_see" = 6 or "news"."id_user" in (select "id_user" from "koneksi_user" where to_id_user = $user->id_user) or "news"."id_user" in (select "id_user" from "koneksi_user" where id_user = $user->id_user))

How can I fix this?

Comment: So you just want to get the solution? Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: return \Status::with('likes')
   ->with('user.profil.foto')
   ->with('foto')
   ->with('comments.owner.profil.foto')
   ->with('comments.like')
   //->where('who_see', [6,$user->id_user_group])
   ->orWhereIn('who_see', [6,$user->id_user_group])
   ->orWhereIn('news.id_user',"array([select id_user from koneksi_user where to_id_user=$user->id_user and confirmed='0'])")
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
   ->paginate(20);

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is of the "gimme hte codez" variety.

Comment: I just wanted to ask because I'm trouble, but why is the response I received like that? whether a beginner like me to ask? if indeed this topic would be closed ahead.

Comment: The responses you initially got where harsh because your question wasn't formulated correctly. You just gave a query and asked for the Eloquent code for it, which just looked like you were asking for the solution. Next time include the code you tried from the beginning, as well as an explanation of the problem, and you won't get bad replies. You should also read the [Asking Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) from the help center, to see how you can ask questions the right way here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can see (which is also the one reported in the error message) is with this:

```
->whereRaw('to_id_user = $user->id_user')
```

This will generate SQL code like `WHERE to_id_user = $user->id_user`, which is invalid SQL.

The first problem is that you've got PHP variables inside a single-quoted string. This means they won't be seen as variables, and will simply be seen as part of the string; they won't be parsed.

That would be solved by changing it to a double-quoted string, but that's not the best fix in this case because I'm not clear why you're using `whereRaw()` here at all. It looks like you should just use `where()` instead:

```
->where('to_id_user', $user->id_user)
```

Replace both the `whereRaw()` calls with `where()` calls, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it working. The problem with the code is that you tried to use `whereRaw` for two of the conditions but included the actual variable name within the string, which means that this:

```php
->whereRaw('to_id_user = $user->id_user');
```

will create this SQL condition:

```sql
WHERE to_id_user = $user->id_user
```

so it just uses the literal `$user->id_user` string instead of the actual ID value. To fix that you just have to use the regular `where` method:

```php
->where('to_id_user', $user->id_user);
```

The complete Query Builder code that will generate the SQL query you're looking for, should look like this:

```php
\DB::table('news')
   ->where('who_see', '6')
   ->orWhereIn('news.id_user', function($query) {
       $query->select('id_user')
             ->from('koneksi_user')
             ->where('to_id_user', $user->id_user)
             ->where('confirmed', 0);
   })
   ->orWhereIn('news.id_user', function($query2) {
       $query2->select('id_user')
              ->from('koneksi_user')
              ->where('id_user', $user->id_user)
              ->where('confirmed', 0);
   })
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
   ->get();
```

And for future reference, if for any reason you want/need to use `whereRaw` and pass variables to the condition, you should use bindings to avoid [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection):

```php
->whereRaw('to_id_user = ?', [$user->id_user]);
```