# How to Convert From Raw Query to Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

I have a query syntax like this :

```
return \DB::select(\DB::raw("select * from news where who_see='6' or (news.id_user IN (select id_user from koneksi_user where to_id_user=$user->id_user and confirmed='0') OR news.id_user IN(select to_id_user from koneksi_user where id_user=$user->id_user and confirmed='0'))) order by created_at desc"));
```

But when I use in Eloquent like this :

```
return \DB::table('news')
            ->where('who_see','6')
            ->WhereIn('news.id_user', function($query)
                {
                    $query->select('id_user')
                    ->from('koneksi_user')
                    ->whereRaw('to_id_user=$user->id_user');
                })
            ->WhereIn('news.id_user', function($query2)
                {
                    $query2->select('id_user')
                    ->from('koneksi_user')
                    ->whereRaw('id_user=$user->id_user');
                })
            ->get();
```

I'm getting error like this :

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: 'sintaks error' pada atau didekat « $ » LINE 1: ...ct "id_user" from "koneksi_user" where to_id_user=$user->id_... ^ (SQL: select * from "news" where "who_see" = 6 and "news"."id_user" in (select "id_user" from "koneksi_user" where to_id_user=$user->id_user) and "news"."id_user" in (select "id_user" from "koneksi_user" where id_user=$user->id_user))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 : Raw Query to Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621262/laravel-4-raw-query-to-eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this is because you're trying to use $user inside single quotes. That wont work. As you can see in the error message the $user is placed in the query literally.

Best would be to use query parameters, something like

```
->whereRaw("to_id_user=?", array($user->id_user));
```